# In redux, what happens after reducer change the state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, okta

I am reading the source code of [a react app](https://github.com/mabc224/node-okta-react-redux/tree/master/client/src), which implement OKTA user management API.

One thing that make me confused is how after the state change for example after [logIn](https://github.com/mabc224/node-okta-react-redux/blob/master/client/src/reducers/Login.js)

```
const registration = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'LOGOUT':
            return Object.assign({}, state, {sessionToken: null, error: null});
        case 'LOGIN_ERROR':
            return Object.assign({}, state, {sessionToken: null, error: action.payload});
        case 'LOGIN_SUCCESS':
            return Object.assign({}, state, {sessionToken: action.payload, error: null});
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

I guess [login page](https://github.com/mabc224/node-okta-react-redux/blob/master/client/src/components/Body/Login/LoginPage.js) would be rendered to [profile](https://github.com/mabc224/node-okta-react-redux/blob/master/client/src/components/Body/Profile/ProfilePage.js) page.
But here the reducer only connected to [store](https://github.com/mabc224/node-okta-react-redux/blob/master/client/src/index.js). Then how does this work?

PS: I attached wrong code at first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `react-redux` plug-in is the glue between `redux` and `react`. The plug-in *subscribes* to the store to be called whenever the store state changes. Each time the store changes, `react-redux` updates all of it's *connected* components. This is done in a way that is optimal as to not update a component if the part of the store that changed is of no interest to that component.

Comment: For example the reducer shown above, how to see what is its connected components?

Comment: You have to find calls to `connect` in the code. every component that uses `import { connect } from 'react-redux'` is a connected component. See https://github.com/mabc224/node-okta-react-redux/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=connect&type=